# Is it possible to simulate contacts other than local contacts in IOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, contacts

I'm trying to create a app which will access contacts from all different types of contact sources. However I haven't found any good way to simulate contacts other than the local source. I.e. I want to test out fetching contacts from:

- kABSourceTypeExchange,
- kABSourceTypeExchangeGAL,
- kABSourceTypeMobileMe,
- kABSourceTypeLDAP,

Does anyone know or have a suggestion how these different sources could be set up in the IOS simulator?

Comment: Interesting question, though I would not keep hopes too high or even hold my breath for too long to look out for a solution, in the end its much more reliable and safe to use a proper device for testing.

Comment: @Till thanks for the support. I will start to test it on a device then, but it would have been sweet to be able to run it through a simulator for debugging purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using unit tests with mocks instead of real data?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do i so setup the iCloud account in the simulator. I've tried it in iOS 7, before it, I didn't try it.

Other types can't be added, because in the simulator there is no other way to add other accounts.